# Does the wash rule apply for naturally expired option contracts

Tags: taxes, income-tax, wash-sale

Does the wash sale rule apply to options expired worthless? for example, my BA Aug 18 call expired worthless (Just expired not sold) will this loss be considered a wash sale if I purchase BA long call option again today?

Thanks,
Prashantha

Comment: Other duplicates: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117623, https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105053

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter if it would be considered a wash sale or not if the replacement option expires (or is closed) before the end of the year.

Comment: I consider Fairmark to be a reliable source of information.  Read the section about[Losses on Options](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-options/) here.